# unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile

Tags: php, docker

When I input

`docker build -t tutum/apache-php .`

in docker, it will output the error

`unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: GetFileAttributesEx C:\User\gao\Dockerfile: The system cannot find the file specified.`

What does this mean? Any advice is helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Please show your dockerfile. This error means that it try to run symlinks on Window environment. It's imposible.

Comment: @NguyenSyThanhSon What is a dockerfile?

Comment: The Dockerfile is the input to the build, so if you don't have a Dockerfile, what are you building?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means your `Dockerfile` is missing or incorrectly named. If you want to build a differently named Dockerfile, you can run `docker build -t tutum/apache-php -f ./Dockerfile.dev .`

You also appear to be trying to build in a namespace that is in use (tutum) which is strongly recommended against. If you want their image, just run a `docker pull tutum/apache-php`.

Comment: I have already pulled image: ```docker pull tutum/apache-php```. So what I just need to do is to create a new Dockerfile by inputting ```docker build tutum/apache-php -f ./Dockerfile.dev```?

Comment: ```docker build tutum/apache-php -f ./Dockerfile.dev``` doesn't work, and ```MINGW64``` returns that ```build requires 1 argument```

Comment: Sorry, the markdown back tick was on the wrong side of the period in my answer.

Comment: But it stills says ```build requires 1 argument``` and ```Usage: docker build [OPTIONS] PATH | URL | -```.

Comment: Apparently I was missing my caffeine that morning. But really, just needed to pass the dockerfile name with a -f since you were using a different name for your dockerfile. Of course if you didn't make a Dockerfile, then you really should ignore the first half of this answer since it doesn't apply to you.

Answer (score 2):

so I actually removed the dockerfile which I was previously using and replaced it with new dockerfile but while running build command I got this error due to the command still pointing to the same docker file.
so just run `sudo docker build -t username/tag -f ./$dockerfile name .`