# Docker build Error: no such file or directory

Tags: docker

I am trying to do a basic docker learning and building an image.

My directory structure currently looks like below:

```
/Documents/docker_test/
├── docker_python
├── hello_world.py
```

The file `docker_python` is the docker file name. `hello_world.py` is a basic hello_world python script I am trying to run it by default when the container is created of the image.

The contents of that docker file look like below:

```
### Dockerfile 

# Created by Baktawar

# Pulling from base Python image 

FROM python:3.6.7-alpine3.6

# author of file
LABEL maintainer=”Baktawar”

# Set the working directory of the docker image 
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app


# packages that we need
RUN pip install numpy && \
    pip install pandas && \
    pip install jupyter


EXPOSE 8888

ENTRYPOINT ["python"]

CMD ["hello_world.py"]
```

When I run it using

```
docker_test$ docker build -t docker_python . 

unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /Documents/docker_test/Dockerfile: no such file or directory
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38089199/unable-to-evaluate-symlinks-in-dockerfile)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make the build work immediatly, your build command should be:

```
docker build -f docker_python -t docker_python .
```

By default, the build command will look for a file named `Dockerfile` in the build context that you supply (in your case you supply `.` aka. the current working directory). If you want to override this default, use the -f switch and supply your filename. Note that the `Dockerfile` always needs to be in the build context.

The `docker build` syntax simplified:

```
docker build -f <dockerfile> -t <imagetag> <buildcontext>
```

If you rename the file `docker_python` in your project, to just `Dockerfile`, you can simply build with the command that you are already trying:

```
docker build -t docker_python .
```

The [docker build reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) is a worthwhile read if you want to learn more.

**Update**

Since you are having trouble with the maintainer LABEL now, I will include a full Dockerfile for you here:

```
### Dockerfile 
# Created by Baktawar
# Pulling from base Python image 

FROM python:3.6.7-alpine3.6

# author of file
LABEL maintainer="Baktawar"

# Set the working directory of the docker image 
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app


# packages that we need
RUN pip install numpy && \
    pip install pandas && \
    pip install jupyter

EXPOSE 8888

ENTRYPOINT ["python"]

CMD ["hello_world.py"]
```

I only replaced the double quotes in the line:

```
LABEL maintainer="Baktawar"
```

**Update**

Next issue seems to be with the numpy installation. And yes, this is indeed a known issue on alpine. I managed to solve the issue with the following Dockerfile:

```
### Dockerfile
# Created by Baktawar
# Pulling from base Python image

FROM python:3.6.7-alpine3.6

# author of file
LABEL maintainer="Baktawar"

# Set the working directory of the docker image
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

# Install native libraries, required for numpy
RUN apk --no-cache add musl-dev linux-headers g++

# Upgrade pip
RUN pip install --upgrade pip

# packages that we need
RUN pip install numpy && \
    pip install pandas && \
    pip install jupyter

EXPOSE 8888

ENTRYPOINT ["python"]

CMD ["hello_world.py"]
```

Apparently, numpy requires some native libraries to be able to install. I also upgraded pip for you, I got a warning about the version.

To your question, should you build like this:

```
docker build -f dockerfile -t docker_python .
```

If you `Dockerfile` is named `dockerfile` - the answer is "Yes". You can only ommit the `-f` switch, if your `Dockerfile` is named exactly `Dockerfile`. It is case sensitive.

Comment: Hi Thanks. Ok so I renamed this file to just dockerfile. It does't take Dockerfile. Wants no caps. But now I see this error. 

Step 2/8 : LABEL maintainer=”Baktawar"
failed to process "”Baktawar\"": unexpected end of statement while looking for matching double-quote

Comment: I now notice, that your double quotes surrounding the LABEL maintainer="Baktavar" are not "kosher". Replace them with new double quotes that you type yourself. (I also edited my answer now - you can use that if you want to)

Comment: Ok. Now I am not sure why am I getting this error in getting numpy installed. 

 ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for numpy
  Running setup.py clean for numpy
  Complete output from command /usr/local/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-n80erkug/numpy/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" clean --all:
  Running from numpy source directory.

Comment: Got the double quotes thing. It runs but now it throws error in installing numpy etc. See the comment above

Comment: also quick question. When I rename it to dockerfile, why do i need to do docker build -t docker_python . ? Shouldnt it be then 

docker build -t dockerfile . ? This is what I did and it works

Comment: Well, the `-t` swithc means **tag**, this is how you name your image. While the `-f` switch means "path to Dockerfile", so that is how you tell `docker build` where your Dockerfile is located. You only need to use the `-f` switch if you Dockerfile is named something else that `Dockerfile` or `dockerfile` - and if it is located somewhere other than the root of the build context that you pass to `docker build`. I just tested, and it seems that it's ok for the `Dockerfile` to be named both **dockerfile** and **Dockerfile** for it to be found by default. Is the answer working for you?

Answer (score 0):

That error is happening because, by default, docker build expects a file called *Dockerfile*. Since yours is called docker_python, you need to use the **--file , -f** option, and then pass the name of your file.

```
--file , -f     Name of the Dockerfile (Default is ‘PATH/Dockerfile’)
```

Check the [Official Docker Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) for more information.